# Drop-down list automatically becomes multiple

Tags: c#, .net-core

Can anyone explain why my drop-down list automatically allows multiple selections?

I'm quite new to Net Core and this is the first time I add a drop-down and I'm obvisouly doing something wrong. Everything works technically, the drop-down list is populated and the Model gets the correct data when posting but for some reason the *multiple* attribute is automatically set for the drop-down list.

View

```
<select asp-for="@Model.fooForm.CountryRows"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.fooForm.CountryRows,"CountryCode","CountryName"))"
        class="form-control">
    <option>Please select Country of use</option>
</select>
```

ViewModel

```
namespace foo.Models.ViewModels
{
    [Bind(Prefix = nameof(fooIndexRootVM.fooForm))]
    public class fooVM
    {
        public fooVM()
        {
        }

        public fooVM(CountryVM[] countryRows)
        {
            CountryRows = countryRows;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Country of use")]
        public virtual CountryVM[] CountryRows { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller/Service

```
public async Task<fooIndexRootVM> GetCountries()
{
    var countryRows = await fooContext.Country
        .OrderBy(c => c.CountryCode)
        .Select(c => new CountryVM
        {
            CountryCode = c.CountryCode
            ,CountryName = c.CountryName
            ,CountryBlocked = c.CountryBlocked
        })
        .ToArrayAsync();

    return new fooIndexRootVM
    {
        fooForm = new fooVM(countryRows)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN: The select tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-select-tag-helper)

> The Select Tag Helper will automatically generate the multiple =
>   "multiple" attribute if the property specified in the asp-for
>   attribute is an IEnumerable.

So in your case the model it's looking at represents a list for `asp-for="@Model.fooForm.CountryRows"`.

In order to fix this you can add new property for selected country to model

```
public virtual CountryVM SelectedCountry { get; set; }
```

Then `asp-for` should be like this:

```
<select asp-for="@Model.fooForm.SelectedCountry"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.fooForm.CountryRows,"CountryCode","CountryName"))"
        class="form-control">
    <option>Please select Country of use</option>
</select>
```